# Coefficient of $1$ in the expansion of $\left(1+x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n$

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

What is the coefficient of $1$ in the expansion of $(1+x+\frac{1}{x})^n$? In other words, what is the sum of the coefficients of $x^ky^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x+y)^n$? Here, $n$ is a positive integer. To be specific, the coefficient is
\begin{equation*}
c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}.
\end{equation*}
If there is no explicit formula, an asymptotic formula with some analysis is also very fine and appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612713/determine-the-coefficient-of-xayb-in-the-expansion-of-1xyn?rq=1

Comment: @Gary That multinomial formula only gives the formula for each coefficient of $x^ay^b$. Here the coefficient of $1$ is a summation of such terms. What I prefer is a closed form or an asymptotic formula.

Comment: You should expand your question by writing down that formula and specify that you are looking for a closed form of that sum.

Comment: It appears to be https://oeis.org/A002426, it has some formulas in it (e.g. $a_n \sim d \frac{3^n}{\sqrt {n}}$ with $d=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3/\pi}$)

Comment: @Sil Thanks a lot!

Comment: Long ago, I determined the asymptotics of these numbers and found $$
\frac{{3^{n + 1/2} }}{{2\sqrt {\pi n} }}\left( {1 - \frac{3}{{16n}} + \frac{1}{{512n^2 }} + \frac{{263}}{{8192n^3 }} -  \cdots } \right)
$$ for large $n$. I used the generating function, Darboux's method and some asymptotics of gamma function ratios. There is an ugly formula for the coefficients in terms of Nörlund polynomials.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the asymptotics, Gary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probabilistic approach: consider the random variable $X$ taking values on $\{-1,0,1\}$ with equal probability. Then its [GF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) is $G_X(x)=\frac13 (1 + x + x^{-1})$.

Also, $E[X]=0$ and $\sigma^2_X=E[X^2]=\frac23$

Now, let $Y= \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ where $X_i$ are iid with same distribution as above. Then  $E[Y]=0$ and $\sigma^2_Y=N \frac{2}{3}$

Also $P(Y=0)=3^{-N} g_0$ where $g_0$ is the independent term in $(1 + x + x^{-1})^N$

But for large $N$, using [CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem):

$$ P(Y=0) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2_Y}}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4 \pi N}}$$

Hence $$g_0 \approx 3^N \sqrt{\frac{3}{4 \pi N}}=3^{N+\frac12} \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi N}}$$

This first order asymptotic approximation could be refined ([eg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21931/refining-the-central-limit-theorem-on-discrete-random-vars)).

Answer (score 1):

Since the coefficient of $1$ corresponds to the coefficient of $x^0$ we have:
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x+1/x)^n &= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni (1+x)^{n-i} x^{-i}
\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i}\binom ni  \binom{n-i}jx^{j-i}
\end{align}
$$
so what you are looking for is the case $i=j$:
$$
\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2};1;4\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n-i}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!}{i!^2(n-2i)!}
$$